# Swift right padding / trailing not taken into account

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to get my StackView centered on the screen and also add a padding on each sides (left & right) of 20 to get margin with the screen:

[image]

but the left margin is not taken into account:
[image]

result is the following:

[image]

how can I handle the right margin ? I also had the same problem for other type of objects (not a StackView).

Comment: If you're giving left and right constraints, you probably don't have to give horizontally Center constraint

Comment: Yes, often times if you signify that you want a UIImageView to be have constraints on both sides of the view then Center X will often interfere with the first two constraints. Try removing that, if it does not work try setting the height and width to see if that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are only using the minimum number of constraints needed to establish the frame for your view.  For example:

- Leading constraint & width constraint
- Trailing constraint & width constraint
- Center X constraint & width constraint
- Leading constraint & trailing constraint

Incorrect examples would be:

- Center X constraint & trailing constraint (doesn't specify where the leading edge should go)
- Center X constraint & leading constraint & trailing constraint (more constraints than necessary, plus unless the leading and trailing constraints are equal, they will be in conflict with the centering

The other thing I'm seeing is that you don't have any constraints for top / bottom / height (the vertical axis) so Interface Builder is warning you that you don't have enough constraints to correctly position the view. Make sure that you don't have any red errors or red constraints in Interface Builder, otherwise the layout is undefined or ambiguous.

Comment: that's a confusing feature of Xcode...as I'm quite new managing conflicts of constraints  is a nightmare for me....